# Android: Set size of ImageView (GIF) to dimensions of source

Tags: android, image

:)
I am using an ImageView and I display gifs in it. The problem is for example this gif: http://media3.giphy.com/media/110U0ZUA6mPxqE/200.gif has different dimensions than this: http://media0.giphy.com/media/10YsmVhdN1S6wE/200.gif and I display the gifs in a listview. The gif which has more or less the same height and width is shown good. But the gif which has unreasonably different width and heigt shows only a part of the gif..
 This is my Item:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewGif"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:minWidth="300dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarSearchedGif"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

To sum up, the question is how can I show the full gif in my imageview even when the dimensions of the gifs are different.

Comment: please add your source code for load gif to ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

you can try removing  android:scaleType="fitCenter" , and set android:adjustViewBounds="true" to your imageview.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want the entire image to display in an ImageView, you have two choices.  You can either stretch it to fit the size of the ImageView with this option:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Or you can reduce the size of the image to fit the ImageView without changing its aspect ratio:

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

Refer to the [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) for details.